# How to pass parameters with bind (jQuery -event handler)?

Tags: jquery, parameters, bind

I have these two lines

```
 $('.closeimg_jq').mouseover({close:"closehover.png"},hoverimage);                    
 $('.closeimg_jq').mouseout({close:"close.png"},outimage);
```

How can I use bind to substitute these two lines? I want to pass the parameters to the following:

```
 $('.closeimg_jq').bind({mouseover:hoverimage},{mouseout:outimage});
```

The first works just fine when I call the parameter e.data.close.

Comment: What does the documentation for `bind` say - is that possible?

Comment: note that `bind` has been superseeded by `on`.

Comment: I think your syntax for the second bind is incorrect. It should be `{mouseover:hoverimage, mouseout:outimage}` (one object with multiple keys), not `{mouseover:hoverimage},{mouseout:outimage}` (several one-key objects).

Comment: I haven't tried your suggestion yet, but the bind in the example works fine

Comment: I think it works for `mouseover` only, and the second object is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If the code does not use dynamically created objects such as in your example, just create the object within the function body.

```
$('.clouseimg_jq').hover(function(){
   var obj = {close:"closehover.png"};
   //...do something
},function(){
   var obj = {close:"close.png"};
   //..do something
});
```

Comment: I was assuming the signatures of `hoverimage` and `outimage` could not be changed; then you would need to modify the event object to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with the callback-map form of `bind`, but you can still use method chaining to shave off a few characters when making multiple calls on the same object; jQuery supports method chaining wherever possible:

```
$('.closeimg_jq')
  .mouseover({close:"closehover.png"},hoverimage)
  .mouseout({close:"close.png"},outimage)
```

P.S. What are you trying to do - shouldn't that be done in pure CSS using `background-image`?

Comment: Yes, css can be used. It is just an example for event handling

Comment: I think that jQuery has to be used when the path to your images folder is different every time. For example project/stats/index.html project/index.html . If you need the image in every place, how can you do it with css? This is the reason why sometimes I change css through jQuery

Comment: @tasos URLs in CSS are relative to the CSS file.